# Anchor text does not wrap properly

Tags: css

I need the anchor text to wrap to the second line and still maintain the layout.
I have tried everything and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
[image]

Above is how I want it. My demo site where u can see the live layout : http://www.iamvishal.com/residen/?q=node/54

I have tried many variations

max-width
word-wrap

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please don't post links to live sites that can potentially change, invalidating your original question. Try posting a fiddle or sketch link, and preferably include relevant HTML/CSS code in the question.

Comment: I don't understand what it should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange wrapping is due to the use of `padding` on an inline element.  You should either move the `padding` to the `li` elements instead of the anchors or change the anchors to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

I played arnd with your CSS on your website. This seems to do the trick. Do post your css and html on jsFiddle so we can better help you.

```
 #navigation .links, #navigation .menu {
   text-align: -moz-center;
 }
```